# Hibernate foreign key relation - list() makes unnecessary sql queries - setMaxResults ignored

Tags: hibernate, list

First of all, this is the first time that I use Hibernate so my questions might seem naive.

I have two tables, DsJobs and DsEvents. Events has a foreign key relationship on the DsJobs table (EID column in DsJobs table corresponds to the ID column of DsEvents table).

I have creted the mapping with anotations, what I care about is unilateral relation, so I have a 'dsEvents' property in DsJobs table annotated with @ManyToOne:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DsJobs")
public class DsJobs  implements java.io.Serializable {

...

     private DsEvents dsEvents;
   ...

     @Id
    @Column(name="JID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public long getJid() {
        return this.jid;
    }

    public void setJid(long jid) {
        this.jid = jid;
    }

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="eid")

    public DsEvents getDsEvents() {
        return this.dsEvents;
    }

    public void setDsEvents(DsEvents dsEvents) {
        this.dsEvents = dsEvents;
    }
....
}
```

I want to retrieve the list of Jobs records from the databse and restricte them with setFirstResult and setMaxResults. This is the call i make:

```
return (ArrayList<DsJobs>) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from DsJobs log").setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(rows).list();
```

This code returns an ArrayList of DsJobs object and inside every DsJobs object there is a DsEvents object, correctly instantiated.

My issues are two:

1. When I see the HQL executed there are unnecesery SELECT calls to the database, one for every DsJobs record. So for each DsJobs record, there is a SELECT in the DsEvents to get the coresponding event, by event id. This is unacceptable for performance, since with simple JDBC I can get all the data I need with a inner join SELECT stament. I am probably doing something completely wrong, please let me know what and if you know how I should proceed.
2. The setFirstResult and setMaxResults seem to be completeley ignored by Hibernate, I always get all records from the database. How can I fix that?

I will greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I see the HQL executed there are unnecesery SELECT calls to the database, one for every DsJobs record.

Yes, this is the dreaded n+1 select problem.  This only happens when you enforce some RI constraint on your relationship (one-to-ones, for example, or unique constraints).  The mapping you're showing us doesn't appear to have these problems, which makes me think you're not showing us the actual mapping that is causing you trouble.  Please post the actual code, not some generalized, abbreviated version of it.

> The setFirstResult and setMaxResults seem to be completeley ignored by Hibernate, I always get all records from the database. How can I fix that?

This code is also fine.  Which means you're not showing us the actual code that's causing you trouble.

Comment: This is exactly my issue thank you for your answer. I don't have the complete understanding of why this is happening, but I was able to fix the first issue with this query: from DsJobs log left join fetch log.dsEvents .

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you may want to read about Lazy/Eager loading. In your case, it seems you want Eager loading, ie, retrieve all data at once. See this wiki page for more details: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies

For 2, your usage sounds correct. I would need more details to see how it's wrong.